# Preload and Scan into a struct in GORM of Golang?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I created 2 model: User and Order. Assuming a one-to-many relationship between User and Order like the following:

```
type User struct {
    ID       uint
    Name     string
    Orders   []Order // Assuming a one-to-many relationship between User and Order
}

type Order struct{
   ID uint
   UserID uint
   User User
}
```

I created UserDTO for response data for Front End like the following:

```
type UserDTO{
    Name     string
    Orders   []Order
}
```

Then I want to preload Orders from User and scan query result to UserDTO:

```
var userDTO UserDTO

// Preload the "Orders" association and scan into the UserDTO struct
db.Model(&User{}).Preload("Orders").Where("id = ?", userID).Find(&userDTO)
```

With this query above it raise a error: `invalid field found for struct UserDTO's field Orders: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface`

I know I can do with the way:

```
var user User
db.Model(&User{}).Preload("Orders").Where("id = ?", userID).Find(&user)
```

and then convert user from User type to UserDTO type.

But I want to know  that with previous way whether GORM can support and let me know how to fix the error above?